# Help me find a certain tile pattern?

Tags: tile

Sorry if I'm asking too much or if it is inappropriate, and it is a long shot any way, but it is the best I can think of. I had my bathroom done in these tiles over a year ago, and I have to do some work and will have to break some of the tiles. Unfortunately I can't get in contact with the guy who put them up and ask him where he got them, but maybe somebody here happens to know where to get them or what they are called. It will help if this is in UK :-)

Here's a picture:

[image]

So, any guess?

Comment: It looks like a marble/granite tile if it feels like stone by touch. Take the photo with you to the nearby tile outlet, you might be able to get a close match.

Comment: I agree with cultured marble but shopping questions are off topic.

Comment: Have you gone to a tile store to see if you can find a matching tile?

Comment: Crema marfil   Marble tile.  Maybe

Comment: You might try popping out the tiles you need to remove, rather than hammering to break them up. A wide, flat chisel can sometimes be quite effective at popping them off the wall/floor, particularly if you cut out the grout first.

Answer (score 1):

You should resign yourself to the idea of not finding an exact match. All such products (whether natural or man-made, i.e. "cultured") have a large variation of color and pattern, even amongst tiles that come out of the same box. Manufacturers, distributors, and installers typically warn end-users of this.

The best you can likely hope for is something similar, but even that will require searching around...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what I have. Made in Spain and purchased in US in 2015, quite likely available in UK as well. Mine seems a bit lighter but it does come in darker shades (I received a box of darker tiles by mistake). The edge has a slight radius. If your edge is a sharp 90 then you probably have a natural stone tile.
[image]
[image]